# why is that the filepath.Walk example has build tag excluding windows and plan9

Tags: go

at https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#Walk

the code example is

```golang
// +build !windows,!plan9

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/fs"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func prepareTestDirTree(tree string) (string, error) {
    tmpDir, err := os.MkdirTemp("", "")
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("error creating temp directory: %v\n", err)
    }

    err = os.MkdirAll(filepath.Join(tmpDir, tree), 0755)
    if err != nil {
        os.RemoveAll(tmpDir)
        return "", err
    }

    return tmpDir, nil
}

func main() {
    tmpDir, err := prepareTestDirTree("dir/to/walk/skip")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("unable to create test dir tree: %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    defer os.RemoveAll(tmpDir)
    os.Chdir(tmpDir)

    subDirToSkip := "skip"

    fmt.Println("On Unix:")
    err = filepath.Walk(".", func(path string, info fs.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("prevent panic by handling failure accessing a path %q: %v\n", path, err)
            return err
        }
        if info.IsDir() && info.Name() == subDirToSkip {
            fmt.Printf("skipping a dir without errors: %+v \n", info.Name())
            return filepath.SkipDir
        }
        fmt.Printf("visited file or dir: %q\n", path)
        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error walking the path %q: %v\n", tmpDir, err)
        return
    }
}
```

why do the go authors excluded windows and plan9 ?

Comment: This is an example, not production code.

Comment: @Volker this a weirdness whe you expect the language to b cross platform  = )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow this changes was added with the commit message

`make Walk example runnable in the playground`

- https://github.com/golang/go/commit/940811922fb528fabda91a2b2dbb401a06aeb1b3
- more comments at https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/122237/

Comment: I accept because after reading your links (great findings) i could not make sense myself :s

Comment: So you saying that links are OK? ;)

Comment: those commits at those that introduced the changes and unfortunately it still does not make sense. It seems related to some problems in godoc. There may be more to explain but how useful will it be to others if its an artifact due to build ? maybe we should add a small message to say that this an artifact readeres should not care about.

Comment: if you can make sense of it, that s great. I did not so far. reading again.

Comment: Examples are tests (same as other tests) and my guess was breaking or not running in some os specific pipelines (win/plan9). I am not familiar with plan9, with `win` maybe some cool way to walk directories wasn't available in windows (and was fallback to previous version that used syscalls). Walk (uses some specific to walk directories)

Comment: maybe it is just that `tmpDir, err := prepareTestDirTree("dir/to/walk/skip")` the path here. Not windows compatible !

Comment: comment from Mostyn  - "Still debugging this, I suspect that it's a godoc bug (it only appears if the prepareTestDirTree function is top-level, even with a fairly minimised testcase).  I will dig deeper before filing a godoc bug- not sure if this is worth putting on hold for now?"....

Comment: i think that makes it for anyone having the question